# How Can I Convert of String To Integer Value in a List in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, hash

This is my code which i did for my project and it takes values from csv file. I got a error from which the data u=in the csv file is taken as string instead of integer. How can i convert it to integer values or float values?

```py
import pandas as pd
proper = []
with open("C:\\Users\\krupa\\Downloads\\proper.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        order_id =tokens[0]
        country = tokens[1]

        proper.append([order_id,country])

        #print(proper)

proper = {}
with open("C:\\Users\\krupa\\Downloads\\proper.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        order_id =tokens[0]
        country = tokens[1]

        proper[order_id] = country
print(proper)

def get_hash(key):
    hash = 0
    for i in range(key):
        hash += 1
    return hash % 100000
get_hash('8469376')
```

**This is the error which I get** 
`TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Post the full traceback so we can see which lines are causing the error?

Comment: it must be `get_hash(8469376)` instead of `get_hash('8469376')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the int class take two parameters `int(str, base=)`. And dont use `hash` as variable as
it is a function in python so have it as a rule, "never use functions as variables"

try:

```
def get_hash(key):
    key = int(key, base=10)
    hash_key = 0
    for i in range(key):
        hash_key += 1
    return hash_key % 100000
get_hash('8469376')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
It is solved now from the code which you sent.
Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
get_hash('8469376')
```

To:

```
get_hash(8469376)
```

Since the key param of `get_hash` function is passed to `range` function, it must be of type int (and not string as you did).